# apc_store apcu_store — Cache a variable in the data store using php

Tags: php, variables, caching, apc

On Windows You will need to install/enable php_apc extension (php_apc.dll) Unfortunately for PHP 5.5 or 5.6 php_apc is not supported. This is why i have this post.

Instead, you will need to use php_apcu for php 5.5 or 5.6 or later and here is how https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-apc-for-php-5-5

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the above instruction https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-apc-for-php-5-5 but it did not work that was because I have not been able to find the correct version for my php.

Finding the correct version is painful and tricky. so I share with you that version that works for me so to give you starting point to compare and look up:

my version of php is 5.5.6 and it works with APCu 4.0.5 http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/4.0.5/windows (you will have to find NTS or TS info in your phpinfo())

here this link helps me find out my version (http://robert-rusu.blogspot.ca/2014/06/install-apcu-on-windows.html)

It is difficult to find version or to list them all so I hope I gave enough info for your searching. good luck!